# Java - Double number return unexpected

Tags: java, math

Probably a very simple math question, but this has me a little bit confused.

Can anybody explain to me why this:

```
public class volumesphere
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double radius = 30.5;
    double PI = Math.PI;
    double volume = (4.0/3) * PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);

    System.out.println(volume);
}
}
```

Is different to this?:

```
public class volumesphere
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double radius = 30.5;
    double PI = Math.PI;
    double volume = (4/3) * PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);

    System.out.println(volume);
}
}
```

Specifically in the line:

```
double volume = (4/3) * PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
```

volume in the first case returns the correct answer at about 1.19*10^5. However, the latter returns a completely different result, around 8.9*10^4.

Can anybody explain this to me please?

Comment: `4/3`  is integer division, it yields `1` .

Comment: Because `4` and `3` are both `int`s, so you will get a rounding error. Using `4.0` you are saying that you want a floating point division rather than an integer division and won't get the same rounding error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `4/3`   the `4` is an `Integer`

In `4.0/3`   the `4` is a `Double`

As integer it won't have decimal values, as double it will ^^

The result is: 1,333333333333 for both the operations, but as `Integer` it won't get the decimal part.

Answer (score 1):

Its because `4/3` is `1` and not `1.333...`.

When you do `int / int`, you get an `int` as the result.
On the contrary `4.0 / 3` is `1.333...`, because the types are `double / int` and therefore result in a `double`.